# Perform an action when an li is the last in the ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this http://jsfiddle.net/mDfQT/15/

```
<ul id="variants" data-size="0">
    <input type="text" id="some_name" class="some_name" placeholder="category name">
</ul>
    <a href="#" class="add_options" data-id="70281696560900">Add more </a>
Number of rows: <span id="count">0</span>
```

So the JavaScript displayed in the fiddle appends an li with a textbox when the add more link is clicked and also removes it when the remove link is clicked.

When I click the remove link I want to check if that's the last li in the ul and if it's the last/only li I want to also remove the input with id some_name.

How would you go about this?

Comment: `ul` elements can only have `li` elements as children. The `input` is invalid there.

Comment: and IDs must be unique on context page

Comment: your also generating duplicate id´s "prop_name" thats invalid, you can check by the class wich index the current li has with http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: Yh sorry ignore that, i quickly wrote that on the fiddle. It still works the same even when its outside. If the li that's begin removed is the last, hide some_name

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mDfQT/18/

Comment: If theres less than three list elements, or in other words only two left, it's the last one added and the one that was there from the start, so remove the last one, and hide the original one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.add_options').on('click', function () {
    if ( $('#variants > li').length < 2 && (! $('#some_name').closest('li').is(':visible') )) {
        $('#some_name').closest('li').show();
    }else{
        var li  = $('<li />',    {'class':'some_id'}),
            inp = $('<input />', {type:'text', id:'prop_name', 'class':'prop_name', placeholder:'Property name'}),
            anc = $('<a />',     {href:'#', 'class':'remover', text: 'Remove'});

        $('#variants').append(li.append(inp, anc));

        anc.on('click', function() {
            if ($('#variants > li').length < 3) $('#some_name').closest('li').hide();
            $(this).closest('.some_id').remove();
        });
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mDfQT/20/)

Comment: Like a boss, thanks! i'll try this out. Nice coding style btw, i'm going to learn alot from it.

Comment: Isn't this removing the category name input too? - @Skyalchemist didn't you say you could'nt remove the objects? I don't understand really

Comment: @LightStyle - nope, it just hides it! Here's one that only hides the elements, no removal at all, with the counter working -> http://jsfiddle.net/mDfQT/21/

Comment: Yes, hiding, but am I wrong or should it keep at least the category input visible?

Comment: The question was to remove the input with id `some_name`, and that's the category input, so I'm assuming the point is to hide that as well when the last added list element is removed ?

Comment: your jsfiddle make it more clear than the original question, thx

Comment: Oh now I understood! Thanks @adeneo, I was missing something :)

Comment: Yh remove some_name(category name) and hide the li's with class some_id.

Comment: @Skyalchemist  next time, try at least to provide valid HTML ;)

Comment: @roasted haha i'll keep that in mind, but then again people who know their stuff don't really make such excuses when they get the general idea.

Comment: One of the best answers i've received on here, i'll learn a lot from your coding style. Thanks.